# BigQuery: Unable to delete table

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a large table (somewhat large < 15 million rows) that we have been filling up with stress and stability testing.  We are trying to delete the table but it is resisting.

Here's what we have tried:

1. delete table from the web console.  No errors...but it doesn't delete the table.
2. delete from command line interface. We get an error message: "BigQuery error in rm operation: Backend Error"
3. We have also tried to delete the whole dataset from the console and that fails as well.  No errors reported.
4. We tried to delete the whole dataset from the commandline.  We get the same error message: "BigQuery error in rm operation: Backend Error"

Other tables with the same schema can be deleted without error.  Our schema does use 9999 columns (the max) which would be the only odd thing we may be doing.

Comment: what's the project id and table you want to delete?

Comment: Project id : 754953140965, dataset: analytics_stress, table: 109_8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hit a bug with tables that have a large number of updates and a wide schema. We're working on a fix.